# Overlapping of sounds

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, avaudioplayer

Why do my music overlap? Is there any way to play it one by one?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
[array insertObject: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Master of Puppets" ofType:@"mp3"] atIndex:0];
[array insertObject: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"music" ofType:@"mp3"] atIndex:1];
[array insertObject: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Start" ofType:@"caf"] atIndex:2];
[array insertObject: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"thx" ofType:@"m4v"] atIndex:3];
[array insertObject: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sound" ofType:@"aif"] atIndex:4];

for (int i=0; i < [array count]; i++)
{
theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[array objectAtIndex:i]] error:NULL]; 
theAudio.delegate = self;
[theAudio prepareToPlay];
[theAudio play];       
}
```

}

in .h:

```
@interface STAMP_AudioViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>{
AVAudioPlayer* theAudio;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 3):

Implement audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying delegate from [AVAudioPlayerDelegate](http://17.254.2.129/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerDelegateProtocolReference/Reference/Reference.html) and start second song from there...

```
NSMutableArray *array ;
int index = 0;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
  [array insertObject: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Master of Puppets" ofType:@"mp3"] atIndex:0];
  [array insertObject: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"music" ofType:@"mp3"] atIndex:1];
  [array insertObject: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Start" ofType:@"caf"] atIndex:2];
  [array insertObject: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"thx" ofType:@"m4v"] atIndex:3];
  [array insertObject: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sound" ofType:@"aif"] atIndex:4];

  theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[array  objectAtIndex:index]] error:NULL]; 
  theAudio.delegate = self;
  [theAudio prepareToPlay];
  [theAudio play]; 

  index++;      
}
```

Now player plays first song..And below given delegate will fire after song is completed..then play second song..Remember you have to release the first player and initialize new AVAudioPlayer and init with second song..

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag{
  [theAudio release];

  if(index > 4)//your array highest index
    return;

  theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[array  objectAtIndex:index]] error:NULL]; 
  theAudio.delegate = self;
  [theAudio prepareToPlay];
  [theAudio play];

  index++;
}
```

This logic should work..I cant find any function in AVAudioPlayer to change the song after initializing..So we need to create new object..:(